# Edge choosability(edge list coloring) of bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

It was proved by Galvin that the list chromatic index of bipartite multigraph $G$ equals to it's (ordinary) chromatic index:
$$\chi_l'(G) = \chi'(G)$$
Let's use definition of choosability below:

[image]

I.e., for $K_{3,3}$, it's line graph $L(K_{3,3})$ is $(3, 1)-$ choosable.

[image]

Suppose we have list assignments to edges of $K_{3,3}$ and $f$ function definition like below:
$$12 \rightarrow L_{1,2} \qquad |L_{1,2}| = 2 = f(12)\\  
14 \rightarrow L_{1,4} \qquad |L_{1,4}| = 2 = f(14)\\
16 \rightarrow L_{1,6} \qquad |L_{1,6}| = 3 = f(16)\\
32 \rightarrow L_{3,2} \qquad |L_{3,2}| = 2 = f(32) \\
34 \rightarrow L_{3,4} \qquad |L_{3,4}| = 3 = f(34) \\
36 \rightarrow L_{3,6} \qquad |L_{3,6}| = 2 = f(36) \\
52 \rightarrow L_{5,2} \qquad |L_{5,2}| = 3 = f(52) \\
54 \rightarrow L_{5,4} \qquad |L_{5,4}| = 2 = f(54) \\
56 \rightarrow L_{5,6} \qquad |L_{5,6}| = 2 = f(56) \\
$$

I want to show that $L(K_{3,3})$ is $(f, 1)-$ choosable.
Or my understanding of $(f, g)-$choosability is not clear and the above statement can not be proved as $L(K_{3,3})$ is $(3, 1)-$ choosable.

Comment: Please give the **source** of your quotation.

Comment: @bof I'm working on edge list coloring of complete graphs.

Comment: You quoted a paragraph of definitions from some book or article. Please give the source of that quotation.

Comment: Ah...sorry... This was from Galvin's paper:
[The list chromatic index of a bipartite multigraph](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~kostochk/math581/galvin.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the graph $L(K_{3,3})$ is **not** $(f,1)$-choosable for the function $f$ defined in your question. To see this, consider a list-assignment where $L_{1,6}=\{a,b,c\}$, $L_{1,2}=L_{1,4}=\{a,b\}$, and $L_{3,6}=L_{5,6}=\{a,c\}$.